# How can I install TV extensions with the new Tizen Studio 1.2?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, tizen-studio, tizen-tv

Since the new 1.2 update for Tizen Studio I can't install the TV extension anymore.

The log file from the package-manager says:

> 14:10:23 [ERROR] [InstallProgressMonitor( 239)] - Cannot install the
>   Tizen Studio package. 14:10:23 [ERROR] [InstallProgressMonitor( 239)]
>   - org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: Cannot install the Tizen Studio package. at
>   org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.wrapExceptionWithGeneralInstallException(InstallController.java:548)
>   at
>   org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.install(InstallController.java:623)
>   at
>   org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.install(InstallController.java:508)
>   at
>   org.tizen.manager.core.Install.InstallProcess.run(InstallProcess.java:37)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.tizen.manager.exception.UMException: Cannot install the Tizen
>   Studio package. at
>   org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.waitForInstallingPackagesDone(InstallController.java:987)
>   at
>   org.tizen.manager.core.InstallController.install(InstallController.java:620)
>   ... 7 more Caused by: java.lang.Exception: The installation was
>   stopped by failure of dependent packages. ==> mingw32-msys-1.0 at
>   org.tizen.manager.core.Install.ManagerableInstallerCallable.call(ManagerableInstallerCallable.java:59)
>   at
>   org.tizen.manager.core.Install.ManagerableInstallerCallable.call(ManagerableInstallerCallable.java:23)
>   ... 4 more

I have installed everything from mingw32-msys and it still does not work.
Before, I could install Tizen Studio and the TV Extension without any problem.

What am I doing wrong now?

I have also tried to install the TV extensions by downloading the package manually and install it from there. That didn't work as well.

Anyone facing the same issue or knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a hotfix. The extension package is working again.